# Java. Adding a Method to test a Constructor

Tags: java

Add a method to test that the Phrase constructor converts the string to uppercase. DO
NOT use the toUpperCase method in your test. Use a literal string (one in quotes like
“this is a literal string”). Remember that you cannot use == to compare two objects
(Strings are objects); you must use the equals method.

> I  am getting a "The left hand side of the arguement must be a Variable" Error.

```
public class PhraseTest {


public boolean phraseTest(String phrase) {

    boolean passes = false;
    if (String.compareTo(phrase("test")) = phrase.toUpperCase()) {

    System.out.println(phrase);
    return passes;
}
}
}
```

> Different Class here.

```
 package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Phrase {
    private String phrase;

    public Phrase(String phrase) {
        phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
        for(char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {
            letters.add(new Letter(c));
        }
    }

    public String getPhrase() {
        return phrase;
    }

    // public String phrase;
    ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();

    public ArrayList<Letter> getLetters() {
        return letters;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues that I can see.

Firstly, you're doing an *assignment* instead of a *comparison* in your `if` condition. This is what's causing the error that you're seeing (you're trying to assign the result of `phrase.toUpperCase()` to `String.compareTo(phrase("test"))`.

The second issue is that there is no `static` method in the `String` class called `compareTo`, so even if you fixed the condition to do a comparison instead of an assignment, this still won't work. There *is* a `compareTo(String)` method in the `String` class, **but it is not `static`**. `compareTo` is an instance method, so you need an object to invoke the method on, you can't invoke it from a static context as you're currently attempting to do.

My best guess for what you want to implement would be this:

```
public boolean phraseTest(Phrase phrase) {
    return "TEST".equals(phrase.getPhrase());
}
```

I have changed the `phrase` parameter to be an instance of the `Phrase` class (otherwise it's not really testing `Phrase` is it?)

Comment: How does this test that the constructor converted the input to upper case?

Comment: It doesn't. Admittedly, I didn't pay enough attention to the `Phrase` constructor so hadn't noticed it was doing it. I will edit to reflect that.

Comment: OK, I've removed my downvote now that you've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my error out - was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: It's errorless and All, But it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yes it does - it returns the result of the `.equals()` call, which is a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do in the line `if (String.compareTo(phrase("test")) = phrase.toUpperCase())` ? String.compareTo is a function, so the compiler is telling you that String.compareTo is not a variable; and phrase is a String (it's the parameter passed in) so I am not sure what you mean? Perhaps you mean `new Phrase(phrase).getPhrase().equals(phrase.toUpperCase())` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use single `=` operation, you are doing an assignment operation, the compiler expect in the left side a variable to hold the right side value in.

So try to change this line:

```
if (String.compareTo(phrase("test")) = phrase.toUpperCase()) {
```

To something like:

```
if (new Phrase("test").getPhrase().equals(phrase.toUpperCase())) {
```

Comment: The edit you just made is invalid. `Phrase(String)` would indicate that `Phrase` is a method. You need to instantiate the `Phrase` class.

Comment: How do I get it to Test a string to make sure I set phrase toUpperCase?

Comment: If you mean the value you're getting from `getPhrase()`, you could add a `toUpperCase()` call after `getPhrase()`.

Comment: "Add a method to test that the Phrase constructor converts the string to uppercase. DO NOT use the toUpperCase method in your test. Use a literal string (one in quotes like “this is a literal string”). "  Sorry, Should have specified.   Doing so with a String.

Comment: So what you need to do is take in a String like "test" and make sure that it's equal to "TEST" without `toUpperCase()`?

Comment: yes, because its called toUpperCase in another Class.

Answer (score 1):

The line that does the testing should be something like

```
if ("TEST".equals(new Phrase("test").getPhrase())) {
```

Or better still, if you're using JUnit, do an Assert

```
Assert.assertEquals("TEST", new Phrase("test").getPhrase());
```

In both cases, we're making a new `Phrase`, and ensuring that the actual text inside it is the upper-case version of what we passed in.

You could even break this into two lines, if this makes it easier for you to understand.

```
Phrase phraseToTest = new Phrase("test");
if ("TEST".equals(phraseToTest.getPhrase())) {
```

Incidentally, your class has a bug, so this test will fail, until you fix the bug.